# Python Implementing Round Robin over a dict

Tags: python, round-robin

I am trying to make a client-server application, where clients register for a request, and get response at a later time.

For fast insertions, I use a `defaultdict`.

```
{
    "john":   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
    "ram":    [2, 6],
    "bruce":  [1, 4, 5],
    "willam": [7, 1],
}
```

The only problem this data structure is susceptible to, is `"john"` who's issuing too many requests, and the server cannot serve other clients fairly in time.

So I thought roundrobin may come to rescue, giving me an iterator that yields clients like this -

```
"john", 0
"ram", 2
"bruce", 1
"willam", 7
"john", 1
"ram", 6
"bruce", 4
...
```

Can anyone please tell me how I can implement such an iterator in an efficient manner?

EDIT: This is what I came up with. Does anyone have a better way to do things?

```
def roundrobin(requests): 
    remaining = set(requests) 

    index = 0 
    while remaining: 
        up_next = set() 
        for key in remaining: 
            try: 
                print(key, requests[key][index])
            except IndexError: 
                continue 
            up_next.add(key) 
        remaining = up_next 
        index += 1
```

It produces the following output

```
ram 2
john 0
willam 7
bruce 1
bruce 4
ram 6
john 1
willam 1
john 2
bruce 5
john 3
john 4
john 5
john 6
john 7
john 8
john 9
john 10
john 11
john 12
john 13
john 14
john 15
john 16
john 17
john 18
john 19
```

Comment: You could interleave all the names. `itertools` probably has an interleave function.

Comment: @Carcigenicate updated answer

Comment: *"better"* how? Do you have a specific problem with it?

Comment: I find it difficult to digest making a new `set()` on each iteration, and adding keys to it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it can get any better than this.

```
def roundrobin2(requests):
    index = 0
    while requests:
        for key in list(requests):
            try:
                key, requests[key][index]
            except IndexError:
                del requests[key]
            else:
                index += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a bucket for each requester, and cycle through with `itertools.cycle`, popping each time.

```
import itertools

all_requests = {
    "john":   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
    "ram":    [2, 6],
    "bruce":  [1, 4, 5],
    "willam": [7, 1],
}

# handle requests:
for requester in itertools.cycle(all_requests):
    request, all_requests[requester] = all_requests[requester][0], all_requests[requester][1:]
    # Intuitively this seems faster than request = all_requests[requester].pop(0), but I could be wrong
    # you should profile this before using it in production code, or see my note below.

    response = handle_request(request)
    send_response(response)
```

Note that I'm often pulling from the head of this list, so you should maybe use `collections.deque` instead which has fast pops and pushes from head or tail.

Comment: I just realized that I need to have a functionality to selectively ignore/select a request, based on a processing step. Does that make sense?

Comment: What I think I need, is the ability to tell the index of `itertools.cycle()`'s iteration

Comment: https://gist.github.com/devxpy/beea2b967913aabdadc144834d0d4722

Here is what I came up with. ( I was already using a deque anyway, since the clients need to have a personal queue )

Comment: Maybe a linked list is what I really need :/

Comment: @DevAggarwal you could use a priority queue (`queue.PriorityQueue` that takes items in the form of `(priority_number, data)` and gets the item with the lowest priority on each `q.get()`) and a dictionary of requesters with values of their current priority. Each request could raise someone's priority (which has the effect of making their responses come later in the queue) with a callback to lower everyone's priority if there's nothing to get from the queue.

Comment: @DevAggarwal something like [this (untested code)](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1783668)

Comment: @DevAggarwal it's not round robin anymore, but it should solve the same problem (make sure that John's later requests get fulfilled after Bruce's, even if Bruce's came in later.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184205/discussion-between-dev-aggarwal-and-adam-smith).